# How do I set a value returned from eval to a variable? (Shell)

Tags: shell

I am trying to set a value returned by eval to a variable in shell.

I have tried the following:

```
y=cat;
eval x$y=9    // x[y]=9;
```

now to print out the value of x[y] i do the following:

```
eval echo \$x$y
```

Now i want to put that into a variable, I tried doing this

```
p = eval echo \$x$y
```

but that's not working. How can i do the following?

p = x[y]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command substitution

```
p=$(eval echo \$x$y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
eval p=\$x$y
```

That should assign the associative value to a variable.